# Conjecture similar to Bunyakovsky-conjecture

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

The Bunyakosvsky-conjecture states the following :

> Let $f(x)$ be a primitive polynomial over the integers. If $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$ and there is no prime $p$, such that $p|f(n)$ holds for every integer $n$, then $f(n)$ is a prime number for infinite many integers $n$.

The condition "for no prime we have $p|f(n)$ for all integers $n$" menas $\gcd${$f(n)|n\in\mathbb Z$}$=1$. Denote $g:=\gcd${$f(n)|n\in\mathbb Z$}. Then, I wonder whether the following statement is likely to be true (or perhaps follows from the Bunyakovsky conjecture.

> Let $f(x)$ be a primitive polynomial over the integers, irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$. Suppose, $g$ is defined as above. Then, there are infinite many primes of the form $\frac{f(n)}{g}$ with $n\in\mathbb Z$.

For example : are there infinite many primes of the form $$\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}$$ with $n\in\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: Maybe I am misreading.  Wouldn't that follow at once from the direct statement of Bunyakosvsky's conjecture?

Comment: @lulu As far as I understood, Bunyakovsky only works for integer polynomials with $\gcd=1$. I did not find anything about the case $\gcd\ne 1$

Comment: Ah, I thought it applied to all integer valued polynomials even if the coefficients were rational.  So little is known about these sort of problems...I don't think there is a single example known of degree greater than $1$.

Comment: @lulu My hope is only that my more general case can be reduced sohehow to the Bunyakovsky.conjecture. Or that there is some evidence for its truth. I also wonder whether $$N+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ produces infinite many primes for every positive integer $N$, if $n$ runs over the natural numbers. Or alternatively formulated. If we start with any positive integer $N$, then we add $1$,$2$,$3$ and so on. Does this sequence contain infinite many primes ?

Comment: Well, let's see.  With your example, $f(n)$ I could instead take $g(n)=f(2n)=\frac {4n^2+2n+2}2=2n^2+n+1$ and apply the conjecture to that.  So, sure.

Comment: I see, great idea. But this would be a stronger formulation becuase we need infinite many primes , when $n$ runs over the even numbers (and not over all integers). Do you also have an idea for $N+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ ?

Comment: Yeah, but that's the nature of these wide open conjectures.  There are no examples so it's easy to make sweeping statements. By the way, my "method" also applies to odd numbers, $h(n)=f(2n+1)=\frac {4n^2+4n+1+2n+1+2}2=2n^2+3n+2$ and again the conjecture applies.